# annotationView delegate and MKAnnotation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mkannotation

So I have create a class X as follows:

```
@interface X : NSObject <MKAnnotation> {
    CLLocationCoordinate2D  coordinate;
    NSString * title;
    NSString * subtitle;
    UIImage * image;
    NSInteger * tag;
}

@property (nonatomic, readonly) CLLocationCoordinate2D  coordinate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * title;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * subtitle;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage * image;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) NSInteger * tag;

@end
```

Inside the:

- (void) mapView: (MKMapView *) mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *) view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *) control

I would like to be able to access the tag property that X has. How is this possible?
Can I do [control tag]? How is this suppose to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second part, the reason for the warning is that you assign plain integer to NSInteger pointer. `NSInteger` is of a type `int` or `long`

So you are doing (incorrectly):

```
NSInteger * tag = 2;
```

**EDIT:**

This is how you could use NSInteger:

```
NSInteger myi = 42;
NSLog(@"int: %d", myi);

NSInteger * i = &myi;    // i is a pointer to integer here
*i = 43;                 // dereference the pointer to change 
                         // the value at that address in memory
NSLog(@"int: %d", myi);
```

Given above, you are trying:

```
NSInteger * i = &myi;
i = 2;                  // INCORRECT: i is an pointer to integer
```

Declare `tag` as `NSInteger` instead of `NSInteger*` and use `assign` in property (I'd give you exact code but I'm on linux atm ...).

**END OF EDIT**

For the first part I'm not sure how is the object of `X` being passed to your method, but you should be then able to do `[yourobject tag]` if the `tag` method is part of the interface that  the method is using to get data from object `X`.

What I mean is that the `MKAnnotation` protocol does not have `tag` property so you have to typecast the object to your type of object e.g. `X *anX = (X*)self.annotation;` ,or wherever the `annotation` object comes from, then you should be able to access tag, `[anX tag]` - if that is the your `X` object

I've found this [example code in Apple docs that uses custom annotation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/WeatherMap/Listings/Classes_WeatherAnnotationView_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009491-Classes_WeatherAnnotationView_m-DontLinkElementID_8).

In the example the annotation is set on view.

When view is drawn it uses data from the object that implements annotation protocol. The object is typecasted to the actual object before values are accessed (see drawing method of the view).

You can see in the controller how new annotations are set in `regionDidChangeAnimated` on the view.

Comment: I don't understand how I am doing it incorrectly, I just initialize the object X and then did an X.tag = 2;

Comment: yes but the `tag` is a pointer to an NSInteger (meaning it stores an address where in memory the integer is stored) as opposed to being just and NSInteger which stores the actual integer. When you try to assign `yourobject.tag = 2` it assumes that it is an address of memory but 2 looks like and integer hence the warning.

Comment: so how do I go in fixing this?

Comment: and inside the delegate method above, I did:
NSLog(@"Test call from accessory view %d", view.annotation.tag);
but then it says
Accessing unknown 'tag' getter method, why is this?

Comment: this is because the annotation is declared to have implemented the `MKAnnotation` protocol which does not have `tag`, if the object is your object then you have to typecast it to your object type as in the example, e.g. `X *anX = (X*)self.annotation;` then you should be able to access `tag`, `[anX tag]` - if that is the your `X` object.

Comment: well, I'll just copy and paste my code http://pastie.org/1520276 so you can see... it's a bit hard to explain what I want...

Comment: I did try this:

- (void) mapView: (MKMapView *) mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *) view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *) control
{
 NSLog(@"Test call from accessory view %d", [((NeighborMapAnnotation) view.annotation) tag];
}

still doesn't work..

Comment: annotation is usually set on the annotation view, in your example you do `self.annotation` but self being your `NeighborMapViewController`, if you set the annotation on the view, AND this method is called (put breakpoint or print statement to verify that you get called), then you should get the annotation from the `view` that is passed in instead of `self`.